# Why do I need to instantiate product twice?

Tags: magento

In the following code, I am printing a list of products, a stock list, and for some reason the only way to make it work is to instantiate the product again whilst looping through them. Otherwise I'm missing the price and stock.

Any ideas?

Here is my code,

```
        $data = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
                        ->addAttributeToSelect('name')
                        ->addAttributeToSelect('type_id')
                        ->addAttributeToSelect('sku')
                        ->addAttributeToSort('name', 'ASC')
                        ->addFilter('type_id', 'simple');

        ?><table dir="ltr" summary="Stock report table">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Id</th>
                    <th>Type</th>
                    <th>SKU</th>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>Price</th>
                    <th>Stock</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <?php

        $i = 0;
        foreach($data as $product){

            $p = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($product->getId());

            echo "<tr>";

            echo "<td>".$p->getId()."</td>";
            echo "<td>".$p->getTypeId()."</td>";
            echo "<td>".$p->getSku()."</td>";
            echo "<td>".$p->getName()."</td>";
            echo "<td>&pound;".number_format($p->getPrice(), 2)."</td>";
            echo "<td>".$p->getData('stock_item/qty')."</td>";

            $i++;
//            if($i == 1){ break; }
        }

        ?></tbody>
        </table>
        <?php
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like Stock isn't part of Catalog module! It's got it's own module called CatalogInventory which deals with the stock_item part of the product.

So I've had to add the following,

When selecting my collection

```
$data = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
                ->addAttributeToSelect('name')
                ->addAttributeToSelect('type_id')
                ->addAttributeToSelect('sku')
                ->addAttributeToSelect('price')
                ->addAttributeToSort('name', 'ASC')
                ->addFilter('type_id', 'simple');
```

And then, when looping instantiating the stock item and returning the qty data item,

```
$stock = Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')->loadByProduct($product)->getQty();
```

Answer (score 1):

You should add these attributes (price and stock_status), before loading the collection:

```
$data = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
                    ->addAttributeToSelect('name')
                    ->addAttributeToSelect('type_id')
                    ->addAttributeToSelect('sku')
                    ->addAttributeToSort('name', 'ASC')
                    ->addFilter('type_id', 'simple')
                    ->addAttributeToSelect('price')
                    ->addAttributeToSelect('stock_status');
```

Comment: This works for Price, as per my answer. However this doesn't seem to work for Stock. I think it's because we are using OrganicInternet_SimpleConfigurableProducts for our products, which means that 'stock_status' just returns a blank 'stock_item' array